# How to make argparse print usage when no option is given to the code

Tags: python, argparse

With the following code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Prepare something code.")
parser.add_argument("-t","--tabular", help="print something in tabular way for EXCEL",
                      action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-v","--verbose", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.tabular:
    print "Tabular print"
elif args.verbose:
    print "VERBOSE"
```

It's only when I execute it the following way, that it prints usage:

```
$ python mycode.py -h
usage: mycode.py [-h] [-t] [-v]

Prepare something code.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -t, --tabular  print something in tabular way for EXCEL
  -v, --verbose
```

What I want to do is to simply run the code: `$ my code.py` without any `-h` option whatsoever to print the usage. How can I do that?

Comment: If you expect exactly one of `-t` or `-v` to be used, you might consider having a single positional parameter with `choices=("tabular", "t", "verbose", "v")` instead.

Comment: That 2010 question only had 1 answer, and it isn't a particularly simple or obvious one.

Comment: @chepner: Can you give specific code. You're right I need exactly one of -t or -v to be used.

Answer (score 22):

That 2010 question covers the same thing, but only has 1 answer.  While that answer comes indirectly from the designer of `argparse`, it does not cover all possibilities.

Here's one which surprised me as to its simplicity:

```
import sys
parser = ...
if len(sys.argv)==1:
    parser.print_help()
    # parser.print_usage() # for just the usage line
    parser.exit()
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Yes you can check all the `namespace` args for default values, but that gets old if there are many arguments.  But here I am just checking whether there are any argument strings.  If none, then call the parser's own help function.

`ipython` does something like this to generate help.  It checks `sys.argv` for some version of `help`, and produces its own help message(s), before even defining the `parser`.

Comment: This is much simpler solution than the alternatives if you only have a bunch of optional arguments but the program needs at least one of those provided to do something meaningful.

Comment: `len(sys.argv[1:])==0` is a long-winded way to write `len(sys.argv)==1`.

Answer (score 3):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Prepare something code.")
parser.add_argument("-t","--tabular", help="print something in tabular way for EXCEL",
                      action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-v","--verbose", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.tabular:
    print "Tabular print"
elif args.verbose:
    print "VERBOSE"
else:
    print parser.print_help()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need exactly one of "-t" or "-v" be used, they aren't really optional. I'd use a positional parameter instead:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Prepare something code.")
parser.add_argument("type", choices=("tabular", "verbose", "t", "v"))
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.type in ("tabular", "t"):
    print "Tabular print"
else:  # Must be "verbose" or "v"
    print "VERBOSE"
```

Then your program would be called using one of the following:

```
$ my_code t
$ my_code tabular
$ my_code v
$ my_code verbose
```

No argument would produce

```
$ my_code
usage: my_code [-h] {tabular,verbose,t,v}
my_code: error: too few arguments
```